# ESLint: Language service timeout ReactJS in WebStorm

Tags: reactjs, webstorm

App.js gives me this error. Yesterday everything was fine today opened WebStorm and it came up with this error:

[image: click here to view image]

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me today. I disabled ESLint *(Preferences-Languages&Frameworks-Javascript-Code Quality Tools-ESLint)* and enabled it again. Message disappeared.

Comment: I realized that the message automatically disappears after some time.

Comment: Just disabling the service which most people will likely want to use is not really helpful. -1

Comment: I wrote that "I disabled and enabled it again".

Comment: how this can be a solution?